# java.io.IOException: COSStream has been closed and cannot be read. Perhaps its enclosing PDDocument has been closed?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I've tried to save PDF file with apache PDFBox but have error

> java.io.IOException: COSStream has been closed and cannot be read. Perhaps its enclosing PDDocument has been closed?

What's the matter?

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(fileName));
try {
    ...
    document.save(storeFileName);
} finally {
    document.close();
}
```

Comment: Please include the rest of your code and mention the version.

Comment: I found problem resolve here Please try it
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55591429/10450654